# How do I load a library using xautoload and libraries?

Tags: 7

I am trying to load the facebook SDK (drupal 7) but I am getting the error

```
Error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found in 
FbPageSyncProcessSubmission::fbpagesync_facebook_sdk_initialize() (
```

My method

First download the facebook api  [Facebook API](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) as recommended

```
cd web/sites/all/libraries
mkdir fbpagesync
composer require facebook/graph-sdk
```

Install xautoload

drush dl xautoload && drush en -y xautoload

In my custom module declare the library

```
function fbpagesync_libraries_info() {
  return [
    'fbpagesync' => [
      'name' => 'PHP SDK for Facebook APIs',
      'vendor url' => 'http://developers.facebook.com/',
      'download url' => 'https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/master.zip',
      'xautoload' => function ($adapter) {
       $adapter->composerJson('composer.json');
     },
      'path' => 'vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook',
      'version arguments' => [
      'file' => 'vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Facebook.php',
      'pattern' => "/const VERSION = '([\d.]*(?!-dev$))/",
      'lines' => 60,
    ],
  ],
  ];
}
```

It looks OK in libraries_load/libraries_detect

```
array (
 'name' => 'PHP SDK for Facebook APIs',
 'vendor url' => 'http://developers.facebook.com/',
 'download url' => 'https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/master.zip',
 'xautoload' => 
   Drupal\xautoload\Libraries\SerializableClosureWrapper::__set_state(array(
   'closure' => 
   Closure::__set_state(array(
  )),
 'moduleName' => 'fbpagesync',
 'libraryName' => 'fbpagesync',
)),
'path' => 'vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook',
'version arguments' => 
  array (
  'file' => 'vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Facebook.php',
  'pattern' => '/const VERSION = \'([\\d.]*(?!-dev$))/',
  'lines' => 60,
 ),
'info type' => 'module',
'module' => 'fbpagesync',
'machine name' => 'fbpagesync',
'download file url' => '',
'library path' => 'sites/all/libraries/fbpagesync',
'version callback' => 'libraries_get_version',
'files' => 
array (
),
'dependencies' => 
array (
),
'versions' => 
array (
),
'integration files' => 
array (
),
'callbacks' => 
array (
  'info' => 
array (
  0 => 'libraries_prepare_files',
),
'pre-detect' => 
array (
),
'post-detect' => 
array (
  0 => 'libraries_detect_dependencies',
),
'pre-dependencies-load' => 
array (
),
'pre-load' => 
array (
),
'post-load' => 
array (
),
),
'post-load integration files' => false,
'installed' => true,
'version' => '5.6.3',
'loaded' => 0,
)
```

The calling code is

```
use Facebook\Facebook;

...

public static function fbpagesync_facebook_sdk_initialize($reset = FALSE) {
 $settings = variable_get('fbpagesync_settings', []);      
 $facebookInit = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => $settings['app_id'],
    'app_secret' => $settings['app_secret'],
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was calling the wrong composer.json. Facebook api has it's own.

The fix is

```
$adapter->composerJson('vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/composer.json');
```